# How is it shown that the definition of the Euler-Mascheroni constant is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, math-history

Sorry if it's trivial - but I would really like to know. Also, how were the hand-calculated approximations derived? A link to Euler's original publication would be perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of finiteness with the least machinery: call
$$ H_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} \; . $$
The sequence 
$$ a_n = H_n - \log n  $$
starts a little high and decreases. 
The sequence 
$$ b_n = H_n - \log (n+1)  $$
starts a little low and increases.
we always have $b_n < a_n.$ However, $a_n - b_n = \log \frac{n+1}{n}$ goes to zero, so the sequences crash together at some point.

If you are worried, we actually have
$$ b_m < a_n $$
for all pairs $m,n.$

Answer (score 2):

From [The Euler archive - E043](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E043.html) page on *De progressionibus harmonicis observationes*:

> *Euler gives $\gamma$ to six decimal places (only $5$ are correct, I think he says) and gives a formal summation that $\gamma$ equals $\frac{1}{2}s_2 - \frac{1}{3} s_3 + \frac{1}{4} s4 - \frac{1}{5} s_5 + \ldots\;$ [...]*
>
> *According to the records, it was presented to the St. Petersburg Academy on March 11, 1734.*

The page has links to the original publication, as well as English and German translations.